# Can I use rootless podman with regular user-namespaces (created outside of podman)?

Tags: namespace, podman, unshare

If I create a uts namespace using [`unshare`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) and set the hostname to `foo`,

```
$ unshare --map-root-user --uts /bin/sh
# echo $$
31882
# readlink /proc/31882/ns/uts
uts:[4026532825]
# hostname foo
```

How can I then use that user-namespace inside of rootless `podman` without running `sudo`, for example this does not work and returns *"Error: cannot find specified UTS namespace path: stat [proc-ns-link]: permission denied"*

```
$ podman run -ti --uts=ns:/proc/31882/ns/uts alpine:3 /bin/hostname
Error: cannot find specified UTS namespace path: stat /proc/31882/ns/uts: permission denied
```

But this does work,

```
$ sudo podman run -ti --uts=ns:/proc/31882/ns/uts alpine:3 /bin/hostname
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `podman` but if someone needs to enter into another namespace using `/proc/31882/ns/uts` then he has to use `setns` syscall.

> In order to reassociate itself with a new network, IPC, time, or UTS
> namespace, the caller must have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability both in
> its own user namespace and in the user namespace that owns the target
> namespace. refer: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html

so, without `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` (sudo) capabilities, a caller cannot enter into another namespace. If that is possible then that is a security issue.

Additional-note:
setting suid bit to `podman` binary will allow running `podman` with `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capabilities without mentioning `sudo` but I hope you are not expecting this answer.

Comment: I've asked a follow up question to this, this still doesn't make sense to me. Can you reconcile this text with my experience with the podman behavior? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625810/how-does-rootless-podman-attach-to-user-namespaces

Comment: ya sure! needed some more info, I have added the comment in the above-mentioned new question.