# How does rootless podman attach to user namespaces?

Tags: namespace, podman

In [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/625794/3285) I get an answer which points to [man 2 setns](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html),

> In order to reassociate itself with a new network, IPC, time, or UTS namespace, **the caller must have the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability both in its own user namespace and in the user namespace that owns the target namespace.**

This doesn't make sense to me though. If I run this command **which does not require root**, I can get a new UTS namespace with the hostname set to `foo` (by way of the `--hostname`).

```
$ podman run --hostname foo -ti alpine:3 /bin/sh -c 'hostname ; readlink /proc/$$/ns/uts'
foo
uts:[4026532995]
```

This container should run `hostname ; readlink /proc/$$/ns/uts` and then immediately complete (container status Exited).

You can reattach (without root) using `podman start --latest --attach`,

```
$ podman start --latest --attach
foo
uts:[4026532995]
```

It does not seem the caller has `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` in it's "own user namespace", and yet it can attach: I read the caller to be the shell which does not have that capability.

Comment: Is `podman` running in a separate user group? It can find using `ls -l $(which podman)`

Comment: What do you mean separate user group? The binary is `root:root`, but I'm calling it as non-root user (`ecarroll:ecarroll`)